# How to check MongoDB user roles in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-query, mean-stack

I have created two users in MongoDB.One has read and write access while other has readonly access.
I would like to verify these roles in node.js.
Can anyone please let me know how to get the logged in user roles.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is

```
db.runCommand(
               {
                 usersInfo:  { user: "user-name", db: "db-name" },
                 showPrivileges: true
               }
)
```

this will return [userInfo](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/command/usersInfo/#dbcmd.usersInfo)

you can also query for multiple users simultaneously

```
  db.runCommand( 
{ usersInfo: [ { user: "user-name1", db: "db-name" }, 
{ user: "user-name2", db: "db-name" } ],
                     showPrivileges: true
                 } )
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but I am getting below error :
        TypeError: db.runCommand is not a function
I am using MongoCLient to connect to database.

Comment: var  MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

Comment: MongoClient.connect("mongodb://user:pwd@localhost:27017/test1", Please let me know if I am making any mistake

Comment: sure will check and reply